# Configuring inputs for a Multiple Input Fuzzy Controller in Labview?

Tags: input, controller, logic, labview, fuzzy-logic

I'm building a fuzzy controller in Labview using the MIMO (Multiple Input, Multiple Output) FL Fuzzy Controller.vi. I designed the fuzzy system using the Fuzzy System Designer, and the .fs file is connected as the "fuzzy system in" of the MIMO Fuzzy Controller VI.

The input values are where I'm having trouble. The fuzzy system is supposed to take two input variables. I have two nodes which give double values, which I then put into an array using the Build Array VI. When I try to link this array to the input values of the MIMO Fuzzy Controller VI, I get the error:

"You have connected two arrays of different dimensions. 
The dimension of  is 2.
The dimension of input values is 1."

How do I change it so that the dimensions agree, i.e. how do I make the MIMO Fuzzy Controller take two inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two nodes which give double values, which I then put into an array using the Build Array VI

I assume you mean that they give 1D DBL arrays, because you can't get from scalars to a 2D array. Most likely you need to right click the BA node and change it to concatenate mode, but that highly depends on the specific VI and I know nothing about the toolkit and about your data source, so I can't say.

If that doesn't help, I suggest you post this to the NI forums, which are more appropriate for this, and include code.

Comment: Changing to concatenate mode seems to work, thank you!